# How to write this code without using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to write the below code without using pandas library?

My csv:

```
TAG   FACTOR   LABEL    WEIGHT
reviews   27.324,                 Highest                37.62548387
```

I did search but could not find a solution.

```
jpd = pd.read_csv(
                file_path, dtype=str).dropna()
dict = jpd.set_index(
                'TAG').T.to_dict()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Just a hint would help. thanks

Comment: Post some data.

Comment: @manwithfewneeds this is a question and answer site, not a code writing service or a tutorial service or a place for "hints". If you are asking for "hints", then this is certainly off-topic

Comment: Thanks @manwithfewneeds I posted some data..

Comment: Are you forbidden from using imports?  What about the standard library?

Comment: I can't use pandas.. others are good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the csv module from the standard library:

```
import csv 

with open('__.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    _ , *header = next(reader)
    d = {}
    for k, *row in reader:
        d[k] = dict(zip(header, row))

    print(d)

{'reviews':   {'JOURNAL_IMPACT_FACTOR': 27.324, 'IMPACT_FACTOR_LABEL': 'Highest', 
               'IMPACT_FACTOR_WEIGHT': 37.62548387}, 
 'hairdoos':  {'JOURNAL_IMPACT_FACTOR': 40.0, 
               'IMPACT_FACTOR_LABEL': 'middle', 'IMPACT_FACTOR_WEIGHT': 50.0}, 
 'skidoos':   {'JOURNAL_IMPACT_FACTOR': 5000.0, 'IMPACT_FACTOR_LABEL': 'medium', 
               'IMPACT_FACTOR_WEIGHT': 430.0}, 
 'kangaroos': {'JOURNAL_IMPACT_FACTOR': 6.0, 'IMPACT_FACTOR_LABEL': 'lowest', 
               'IMPACT_FACTOR_WEIGHT': 3.0}
 }
```